# Where can I find gtag() and dataLayer.push() source code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to understand some specific things of the 2 functions. I can obviously find docs about them, but it seems the source code is not available.
Do you know of any place I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what both are doing right in the installation instructions they give you:

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-IDGOESHERE"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-IDGOESHERE');
</script>
```

The `gtag` function is just a simple wrapper around `dataLayer.push`. All the global `dataLayer` variable is is a primitive array (hence the availability of the `push` method).

The magic comes from the script that Google provides. While the source code is largely obfuscated and uglified, the gist of it is that the global `dataLayer` variable is being proxied and watched for changes.

As you add new entries to the array, Google will see these changes happening and send information back to its servers in realtime. In essence, the `gtag` function and `dataLayer` variable are completely unremarkable and don't really do a whole lot on their own. It's the underlying script that monitors the changes to this variable that's doing the heavy lifting.